# Mortgage payment which starts after a year

Tags: mortgage, terminology

Is there any kind of mortgage in which the first payment due starts after a year? If so, what is it called (I don't mean the one that you need to prove financial hardship).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several years ago, there was a company talking about a new product called a 12 Month Deferral mortgage. They were branding it 12MoDef. The idea is that you would finance a home that you have equity in, and for the first 12 months the mortgage would work almost like a reverse mortgage: the bank would essentially make your mortgage payment for you and take some of your equity in return. After 12 months, you'd start making mortgage payments as normal with your reduced equity.

I found [the original press release from 2007](http://rismedia.com/2007/01/07/california-company-announces-no-mortgage-payment-for-12-months/), and a Google search on the term 12MoDef shows a bunch of articles from that time about the idea. However, I couldn't find anyone offering it currently, and the website 12modef.com is now dead. The old site can be seen on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20070827223208/http://www.12modef.com:80/).

Comment: Good answer, but man what a horrible idea.  I bet the fees were very high.

Comment: @PeteB. Agreed.

Comment: And the walkaways. It was 2007, after all.